# teamcity background continually process

Tags: go, deployment, continuous-integration, teamcity

I want to build the code developed with Golang with Teamcity and run the build file continuously.

I added build steps for this. When I add "`./executable-file`" to these steps, the build on teamcity keeps running.

[image: build steps]

The contents of the run.sh file I created are as follows;

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Runner working..."
sh ./executable-file &
```

But in this case, as in the image below, it kills the sh file and the process that I want to run constantly stops.

[image: output]

In summary; I want an executable file from build to run continuously in the background. I couldn't find how to do this. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: That's quite unusual pipeline. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @BorisMarkov I want to run the project I built. So my goal is to compile the code I push and run it automatically.

Comment: Maybe this could help https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269899

Comment: You cannot - and should not - do this with TeamCity.

Comment: @BorisMarkov I tried using nohup. Teamcity somehow kills that too.

Comment: @Birb Why shouldn't I do this?

Comment: @sercan because the purpose of a build system such as TeamCity is not to replace your task scheduler. TeamCity and possibly many other tools like it has mechanisms around cleaning up and finishing a workload.

Comment: @Birb Thank you. What kind of build should I use to automate the build process?